# admin-ajax.php 500 error when new users try to register

Tags: plugins, themes, ajax

I have WordPress website and I get admin-ajax.php 500 error when new users try to register.

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 
 POST https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500
send    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
s.ajax.s.ajax   @   jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2
S.<computed>    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
(anonymous) @   custom.js?ver=6.0.1:2430
trigger @   base.js:98
_trigger    @   constraint.js:15
onSubmitValidate    @   form.js:60
(anonymous) @   ui.js:36
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

Also I can see error message in server logs

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: date_interval_create_from_date_string(): Unknown or bad format ( days) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/nokri_framework/functions.php on line 696

I have error in server logs for this part of code

```
$days = get_post_meta($product_id, 'package_expiry_days', true);
        if ($days == '-1') {
            update_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', '-1');
        } else {
            $expiry_date = get_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', true);
            $e_date = strtotime($expiry_date);
            $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
            if ($expiry_date && $today > $e_date) {
                $new_expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days"));
            } else {
                $date = date_create($expiry_date);
                date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$days days"));
                $new_expiry = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
            }
            update_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', $new_expiry);
        }
```

Line 696 ( server logs message )

```
 date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$days days"));
```

I update all plugins and theme
I try to deactivate plugins but I still get this error
admin-ajax file has 644 permissions

Full function

```
function nokri_free_package_for_candidate($product_id, $user_id = '') {
        global $nokri;
        if ($user_id != '') {
            $uid = $user_id;
        } else {
            $uid = get_current_user_id();
        }
        if (get_user_meta($uid, '_sb_reg_type', true) == '1')
            return '';

        $candidate_jobs = (int) get_post_meta($product_id, 'candidate_jobs', true);
        $candidate_feature_list = (int) get_post_meta($product_id, 'candidate_feature_list', true);
        // Expiry date logic
        $days = get_post_meta($product_id, 'package_expiry_days', true);
        if ($days == '-1') {
            update_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', '-1');
        } else {
            $expiry_date = get_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', true);
            $e_date = strtotime($expiry_date);
            $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
            if ($expiry_date && $today > $e_date) {
                $new_expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days"));
            } else {
                $date = date_create($expiry_date);
                date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$days days"));
                $new_expiry = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
            }
            update_user_meta($uid, '_sb_expire_ads', $new_expiry);
        }
        /* Job info */
        if ($candidate_jobs != '') {
            update_user_meta($uid, '_candidate_applied_jobs', $candidate_jobs);
        }
        /* free package */
        $is_pkg_free = get_post_meta($product_id, 'op_pkg_typ', true);

        if ($is_pkg_free == 1) {
            update_user_meta($uid, 'avail_free_package', (int) '1');
        }
        /* Feature profile info */
        $days = get_post_meta($product_id, 'candidate_feature_list', true);
        if ($days == '-1') {
            update_user_meta($uid, '_candidate_feature_profile', '-1');
            update_user_meta($uid, '_is_candidate_featured', '1');
        } else {
            $expiry_date = get_user_meta($uid, '_candidate_feature_profile', true);
            $e_date = strtotime($expiry_date);
            $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
            if ($expiry_date && $today > $e_date) {
                $new_expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days"));
            } else {
                $date = date_create($expiry_date);
                date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$days days"));
                $new_expiry = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
            }
            update_user_meta($uid, '_is_candidate_featured', '1');
            update_user_meta($uid, '_candidate_feature_profile', $new_expiry);
        }
    }
```

try

update all plugins and website theme

deactivate plugins and turn on plugins one by one

check admin-ajax file permission ( 644 - ok )

Increase server PHP memory_limit = 256M and max_execution_time = 300

Comment: Can you add your full AJAX function code to check the issue.

Comment: I've added full function code

Comment: Can you check the date format are you using ( YYYY:MM:DD ) this format.

or you can add output of these part of code 
            $e_date = strtotime($expiry_date);
            $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
            if ($expiry_date && $today > $e_date) {
                $new_expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days"));
            } else {
                $date = date_create($expiry_date);
                date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$days days"));
                $new_expiry = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
            }
Issue with date format

Comment: I have user_register field on my localhost in this format 2022-08-09 14:54:04. Localhost DB version - MySql 5.7. Also I use old MariaDB on live server